# writing SQL queries in db2 database

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm new be to DB2/AS400. I know writing sql queries to insert/update in the database but not sure how could i perform same thing in DB2/AS400.Can any body guide me how could i write the sql insert/stored procedure queries in db2 database

Comment: Try something, start with their documentation, and if you get stuck, then come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it with any other SQL database.

Answer (score 2):

STRSQL as suggested previously would work fine but it is a green screen (5250 emulation) option; if you are not familiar with that environment, I would recommend you use the 'Run SQL Script' function from either IBM i Access Client Solutions or IBM i Navigator, whichever is available to you.

Answer (score -1):

On the AS400 command line issue the following command.

***STRSQL***

Start [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzatc/rzatcgetstartsql.htm) and this is typical IBM documentation.  It leaves you guessing  why am I here.